# Font problem when opening SVG file?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, import

I am opening SVG files generated by D3.js code in another computer and seeing a pop-up -

[image]

And the opened file in Illustrator is missing some letters (showing cross sign instead, as if the fonts are missing as the pop-up says). The missing letters are superscripts, negative sign (-).

What is the significance of the pop-up and how do I rectify the missing letters problem?

Answer (score 1):

In d3.js code you need to use another font instead of Arial or default. Try to export with font "Verdana".

Comment: Exact same messages for "Verdana" in d3.js. It is only happening when the - sign is used as superscript, this is the Unicode - http://graphemica.com/%E2%81%BB. Any other way to solve this issue?

Comment: Looks like bug in illustrator. Try to replace '-' with other unique character while exporting from d3. And then in illustrator after successful import  try to use CTRL+F to change character for desired.